# Ignore "The" and "A" when sorting a listview in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, listview

Currently I am making a mini music player / organizer for myself. However, when using a list view, it sorts alphabetically, and doesn't ignore "The" and "A":

1. A Lot Like Me
2. Adiago For Strings
3. Stay Crunchy
4. The Foresaken
5. Time to Pretend

should be:

1. Adiago For Strings
2. The Foresaken
3. A Lot Like Me
4. Stay Crunchy
5. Time To Pretend

It's all loaded from a multi-dimensional array, and I've even tried filtering out "The" and "A" manually, and then display the real name (from a different array), but then it just sorts the displayed name (including "The" and "A")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you could do is to create a customer [comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx) and set it on your `ListView` instance using the [ListView.ListViewItemSorter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemsorter.aspx) property. Then, your comparer is responsible for remvoing "the" and "a" from the start of the items being compared.

When your `ListView` is sorted, it will use this custom comparer to sort with, but the original values including "the" and "a" will be used as display values in the `ListView` (ie. you do not need to modify the values you put in the `ListView` - the comparer just ignores the words you want it to when sorting).

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with a custom comparison method like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Example
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<String> names = new List<String>
        {
            "A Lot Like Me",
            "Adiago For Strings",
            "Stay Crunchy",
            "The Foresaken",
            "Time to Pretend"
        };

        names.Sort(smartCompare);
    }

    static Regex smartCompareExpression
        = new Regex(@"^(?:A|The)\s*",
            RegexOptions.Compiled |
            RegexOptions.CultureInvariant |
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    static Int32 smartCompare(String x, String y)
    {
        x = smartCompareExpression.Replace(x, "");
        y = smartCompareExpression.Replace(y, "");

        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }
}
```

The regular expression strips off any leading "A " or "The " from the strings so that they won't effect the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

This LINQ approach seems to work:

```
string[] input = new string[] {
   "A Lot Like Me",
   "Adiago For Strings",
   "Stay Crunchy",
   "The Foresaken",
   "Time to Pretend"
};

IEnumerable<string> ordered = input.OrderBy(s =>
    s.StartsWith("A ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || s.StartsWith("The ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ?
    s.Substring(s.IndexOf(" ") + 1) :
    s);

foreach (var item in ordered)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

It strips away leading "a " and "the " from the comparison, but does not alter the values in the list.